# I am having trouble using Power Automate to send an email to an email provided in a List form, using "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint"

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

This is my column that I want to use to send an email to the Requestor's Supervisor:

[image: List Column for Supervisor field]

This is my Form highlighting the field I want to use the email:

[image: Form showing Supervisor entry field]

This is my flow, and I can't figure out how to send this to the Supervisor's email provided in the Supervisor field from the form.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPZMA.jpg]

I tried to copy this FLOW which successfully sends an email to the Requestor (Created By Email):

[image: Flow to send email to Requestor]

My problem is I can't find the Supervisor field in the Dynamic Content and my Power Automate knowledge is limited.  I got this far from copying the working flow.  Also, last time I edited this flow I realized that for some reason "Send an Email" is not an option. I am required to use "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint".

Can anyone help?

The Flow Checker says "No errors or warnings". I don't know how to choose the Supervisor's email to send this email to.